# Simple HTML5 drag/drop uploader WITH registration

Tags: php, mysql, drag-drop, uploader

I'm looking for a simple HTML5 drag/drop file uploader script. There are many out there, but would like to have people adding their email address, and after this they can upload files and submit their upload.

#### Requirements

- HTML5
- drag/drop files
- have people adding their email address before they're able to upload
- A login after the upload is not really needed
- must come with example code (for how to implement it into my site), so I can compare their process and implement mine

#### Strongly wished for

- online demo should be available for easier evaluation
- process (from the user's point-of-view) should be as easy as *insert email address › submit › get your upload window › upload*

Now there are lots of examples, I can add some PHP/MySQL additional code to have them register first by adding their email address and lettig them through but I wonder in that case what the order would be and what to store.

So far I'm unable to find one matching the given criteria. Can you tell me some?

Answer (score 3):

I modified this script here, [Mini AJAX File Upload Form](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) to fit your requirements of clients/guest inputting their email before they get to the upload form. You can download it here, [mini-upload-form.zip](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=72868998185991634762). The script will validate and sanitize the email address. I made comments in the index.php file (it's simple). If you have any questions, ask away:)

Here is a demo of the original script (Again, mine will show a simple email input box): **[DEMO](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/)**

[image: Email Input Form]

[image: Ajax Upload Form]

Comment: For me, if permissions are not set correctly, it doesn't create files in the uploads directory but still displays success icon.

Comment: Make sure you have set the right file types in the upload.php file and set the correct permissions for the upload folder accordingly

Comment: In case of wrong file types it should also indicate an error, not success.

Comment: Agreed, this was not me but the people who made the original script, I'll see if I can modify it to do that

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/26312/file-upload?tab=general

Comment: Thank you for this as this makes it more clear indeed.

I can extend it now easily, maybe more people will/can do and share here.

Did you had a reason for using this drag/drop one ? It's clean and simple and good. The other ones are "too big" for what it does ?

Comment: @Matt Exactly, I was looking for a simple, secure, and easy to use interface and this fit the bill:)

Comment: Tom, would it be possible to have in te same request a captcha ? I'm checking out captcha's but there are many and I wonder where you would do the check, first captcha, than email check I would do. Ideas ?